# How file structure comes in Laravel when developing a project

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, laravel

I have been suffering from this problem for several months now. There are lot of tutorials explain about how to implement your code using OOP methods. With parent classes, abstract classes, Interfaces etc.

My problem is where should I create such file structure in frameworks as Codeigniter, Laravel etc. I know only controller folder to define classes. Should I place all the interfaces and parent classes in controller folder? Please explain it's really mess for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading) helped me understand where to put my own libraries.  Give it a shot!

Comment: No problem.  Don't forget to accept the answer so other people who ask the same question can find it.

Comment: But this is not the answer I excepted buddy.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 4, the file structure already exists in your /app folder.

See: http://laravelbook.com/laravel-architecture/

Comment: Thanks for the link. But this is not I expected.

Comment: Can you fine-tune your question? It's vague what you're needing help with.

Comment: I need to know should I define all the logic classes define in controller folder.?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?